How to add a link to another page & to a specific point in draw.io
Is there any way to add a link to some text from page 1, that redirects you to a specific node/place/text in page 2? From what it seems, there's no way to directly do such a thing.
I only found a way to link something to page 2 in general, and not in a pin-point location.
